# How can i Get local Machine Name in VM using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, virtual-machine

How can we get local host Machine Name which is running my VM ?

Example:

> local Machine Name --> **ABC**
>                    VM Machine Name    --> **XYZ**

if I am trying to get local Machine Name in VM I am geting VM Machine Name i.e: XYZ. but here i need ABC.
How can i get ?

I tried `System.Environment.MachineName` and `Dns.GetHostName()` also tried.

Comment: You want the name of the host hosing the VM from within the VM? What's the hypervisor you're using? You may search if it provides some agent for the VM, e.g. VMware Tools, and if that exposes the hosts name in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to get the host name of the VM using System.Environment.MachineName? No, you can't do that at all.

The MachineName is only bound to running machine name (getting the NETBIOS name), in your case the running VM name, not your VM host name.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.machinename?view=netframework-4.7

**UPDATE 1:**
If you stil want to get the VM host name, check the registry value of this registry entry from the VM:

`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Virtual Machine\Guest\Parameters`

In .NET, we can get this value you can use APIs in the Microsoft.Win32.Registry class.

Comment: any reference ? TIA

Comment: He doesn't want the host name of the VM. He wants the name of the machine running the VM.